# Dump displaying HTML

Tags: html, dump

I have a problem.
When I want to make a dump on Symfony 2.x, I have the dump's html displayed:

**DUMP HTML**
[image]

[image]

```
    $documentsUploads = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('BddBundle:ApcDocumentsZeen')->findBy(array('apcProceduresSinistres' => $tache));

    dump($documentsUploads);
    die();
```

This I the same result on all browser I am using (Google Chrome, Firefox etc).
Anyone have an idea ?

Regards

Comment: Please copy/paste the text instead of using images, it will be a lot easier to read, and to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks. I just done it